# How to use python file path inside docker file and write python program's logs to /var/log file on ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu-20.04

I am new to docker stuff. My docker files content:

```
WORKDIR /home/uadmin/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache
COPY . /home/uadmin/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache

#CMD ["pwd"]
#CMD ["ls"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python3"]
CMD ["/home/uadmin/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache/publisher.py"]
```

Command used to run docker image is(keeping the path from where I am running):

```
uadmin@br0ubmsmqtest:~/msw/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache/docker_inputs$ sudo docker build -t queuepublisher:latest . -f publisher_docker_file
```

Command used to run docker container is(keeping the path from where I am running):

```
uadmin@br0ubmsmqtest:~/msw/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache/docker_inputs$ sudo docker container run -v /var/log:/log --rm --name publisher queuepublisher
```

Eventhough `CMD ["pwd"]` prints "*/home/uadmin/msw/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache*" as current directory, the command  `CMD ["ls"]` lists files from */msw/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache/docker_inputs* instead of files from */home/uadmin/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache* . Because of this the last line `CMD ["/home/uadmin/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache/publisher.py"]` results in error :

***/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/home/uadmin/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache/publisher.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory***

I am creating log file inside /va/log/ folder form publisher.py using python logging module. Here is the code snippet of publisher.py:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/example.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.info('This is publisher.py')
```

When I run it using docker, it should write log messages from publisher.py to /var/log/ folder. So only I am sending "-v /var/log:/log" while running docker container.

But it is not at all creating log file under /var/log folder using docker container.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this question: an image only has one `CMD` (and the last one wins), but since you `COPY` the current host directory into the image, it's natural the `ls` would show the same content.  Is your problem that the container doesn't start, or that it does start and it isn't writing logs out?  Can you show the logging setup?

Comment: Yes. I just added them for debugging. Commented them out. Here command ```pwd``` shows current directory as /home/uadmin/msw/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache. Where as ```ls``` lists file from /msw/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache/docker_inputs.  My container creation fails because it is not able to find file from /home/uadmin/queuemgr/mongo_db_cache/. Why so?

Comment: (If you combine both command words into `CMD` and leave out `ENTRYPOINT`, you can `docker run --rm queuepublisher ls` to run the container with an alternate command.)

Comment: The intent here is to run python file publsher.py and write python logs to /var/log folder on ubuntu.

Comment: Here is the logging setup-                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                          
```import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/example.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.info('This is publisher.py')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt some how that we can pass multiple volumes. The below command did the magic for me:

`sudo docker container run -v /home/uadmin/msw/queuemgr:/queuemgr -v /var/log:/var/log --rm --name publisher queuepublisher`

I could run the container with publisher.py successfully. At the same time logging to /var/log folder from publsher.py is successful!